# Object tag added by innerHTML always null onload

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-web-twain

I am creating an object tag `onload`, and after creating it trying to access the object as follows:

```
function loadFile() {



        alert("loading file");
        gform.MOJWebTwain.HTTPPort = 9080;
        gform.MOJWebTwain.IfSSL = false;
        var result = gform.MOJWebTwain.HTTPDownload('myServer', existingDocumentPath);
        alert("result: "+result);
        var errorString = gform.MOJWebTwain.ErrorString;
        var errorCode = gform.MOJWebTwain.ErrorCode;
        if (!result) {
            alert("errorString: " + errorString);
            alert("errorCode " + errorCode);
        }
        document.body.style.opacity="100";

}

window.onload = function () {
    var DW_DWTContainerID = "gform:scan_area";
    var DW_FULLCLASSID = "123456-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456"; // fixed
    var DW_PROCLASSID = "3d25aba1-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456";  // the one in lpk file

    var DW_VersionCode = "6,3,1,0";
    var DW_InWindowsX86;
    var objString = "";

    var DW_ObjectName="MOJWebTwain"
    var DW_Width = 400;
    var DW_Height = 400;
    var DW_CABX86Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAIN.cab";
    var DW_CABX64Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAINx64.cab";
    var LPK_Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTwain.lpk";
    ua = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

    objString += "<object id='" + DW_ObjectName + "' "+"width='" + DW_Width +" ' "+"height='" + DW_Height+"' ";

    if (DW_InWindowsX86) objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX86Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";
    else objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX64Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";

    objString += " classid='clsid:" + DW_FULLCLASSID + "' viewastext>";

    //alert("objString: "+objString);

    objString += " <param name='_cx' value='847'/>";
    objString += " <param name='_cy' value='847'/>";
    objString += " <param name='JpgQuality' value='30'/>";
    objString += " <param name='Manufacturer' value='DynamSoft Corporation'/>";
    objString += " <param name='ProductFamily' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN'/>";
    objString += " <param name='ProductName' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN'/>";
    objString += " <param name='VersionInfo' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN 6,3,1,0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='TransferMode' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='BorderStyle' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='FTPUserName' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='FTPPassword' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='FTPPort' value='21'/>";
    objString += " <param name='HTTPUserName' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='HTTPPassword' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='HTTPPort' value='9080' />";
    objString += " <param name='ProxyServer' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfDisableSourceAfterAcquire' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfShowUI' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfModalUI' value='-1'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfTiffMultiPage' value='-1'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfThrowException' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='MaxImagesInBuffer' value='99'/>";
    objString += " <param name='TIFFCompressionType' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfFitWindow' value='-1' />";
    objString += " <param name='IfSSL' value='0' />";
    objString += " </object>";

    var obj2String = "<object "
        +"classid='clsid:"+DW_PROCLASSID+"'"+">"
        +"<param name='LPKPath' value='"+LPK_Path+"'"+"/>";
        +"</object>";

    //alert("obj2String "+obj2String);

    var obj2String = "<object classid='clsid:"+DW_PROCLASSID+"'>"
        +"<param name='LPKPath' value='"+LPK_Path+"'"+"/>";
        +"</object>";

    var objects_string=obj2String +" "+objString;

    DWTContainer = document.getElementById(DW_DWTContainerID);                          
    DWTContainer.innerHTML = objects_string;

    loadFile();
}
```

**HTML** is as follows:

```
<form id="gform">
  <div id=gform:scan_area"">

   </div>
</form>
```

But I always get that the object I created is `null` in this line:

```
gform.MOJWebTwain.HTTPPort = 9080;
```

If the object was added statically in the page (i.e. not through `onload`), I don't get this exception.

Comment: try with setTimeout :D

Comment: Where is gform being loaded? Show the structure.

Comment: Where's your HTML and other JavaScript (e.g. the editWebScan variable)

Comment: @Zenith, i have edited the code in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed By using setTimeout as follows:

```
setTimeout(function(){
        DWTContainer = document.getElementById(DW_DWTContainerID);
        alert("DWTContainer: "+DWTContainer);
        DWTContainer.innerHTML = objects_string;
        loadFile(editWebScan,existingDocumentPath);
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be error on your HTML part yours is as follows

```
<form id="gform">
  <div id=gform:scan_area""><!--quote error-->

   </div>
</form>
```

**Check this it could give you desire result**

```
<script>
    function loadFile() {
        alert("loading file");
        gform.MOJWebTwain.HTTPPort = 9080;
        gform.MOJWebTwain.IfSSL = false;
        var result = gform.MOJWebTwain.HTTPDownload('myServer', existingDocumentPath);
        alert("result: " + result);
        var errorString = gform.MOJWebTwain.ErrorString;
        var errorCode = gform.MOJWebTwain.ErrorCode;
        if (!result) {
            alert("errorString: " + errorString);
            alert("errorCode " + errorCode);
        }
        document.body.style.opacity = "100";
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        var DW_DWTContainerID = "gform:scan_area";
        var DW_FULLCLASSID = "123456-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456"; // fixed
        var DW_PROCLASSID = "3d25aba1-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456";  // the one in lpk file

        var DW_VersionCode = "6,3,1,0";
        var DW_InWindowsX86;
        var objString = "";

        var DW_ObjectName = "MOJWebTwain";
        var DW_Width = 400;
        var DW_Height = 400;
        var DW_CABX86Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAIN.cab";
        var DW_CABX64Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAINx64.cab";
        var LPK_Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTwain.lpk";
        ua = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

        objString += "<object id='" + DW_ObjectName + "' " + "width='" + DW_Width + " ' " + "height='" + DW_Height + "' ";

        if (DW_InWindowsX86)
            objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX86Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";
        else
            objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX64Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";

        objString += " classid='clsid:" + DW_FULLCLASSID + "' viewastext>";

        //alert("objString: "+objString);

        objString += " <param name='_cx' value='847'/>";
        objString += " <param name='_cy' value='847'/>";
        objString += " <param name='JpgQuality' value='30'/>";
        objString += " <param name='Manufacturer' value='DynamSoft Corporation'/>";
        objString += " <param name='ProductFamily' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN'/>";
        objString += " <param name='ProductName' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN'/>";
        objString += " <param name='VersionInfo' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN 6,3,1,0'/>";
        objString += " <param name='TransferMode' value='0'/>";
        objString += " <param name='BorderStyle' value='0'/>";
        objString += " <param name='FTPUserName' value=''/>";
        objString += " <param name='FTPPassword' value=''/>";
        objString += " <param name='FTPPort' value='21'/>";
        objString += " <param name='HTTPUserName' value=''/>";
        objString += " <param name='HTTPPassword' value=''/>";
        objString += " <param name='HTTPPort' value='9080' />";
        objString += " <param name='ProxyServer' value=''/>";
        objString += " <param name='IfDisableSourceAfterAcquire' value='0'/>";
        objString += " <param name='IfShowUI' value='0'/>";
        objString += " <param name='IfModalUI' value='-1'/>";
        objString += " <param name='IfTiffMultiPage' value='-1'/>";
        objString += " <param name='IfThrowException' value='0'/>";
        objString += " <param name='MaxImagesInBuffer' value='99'/>";
        objString += " <param name='TIFFCompressionType' value='0'/>";
        objString += " <param name='IfFitWindow' value='-1' />";
        objString += " <param name='IfSSL' value='0' />";
        objString += " </object>";

        var obj2String = "<object "
                + "classid='clsid:" + DW_PROCLASSID + "'" + ">"
                + "<param name='LPKPath' value='" + LPK_Path + "'" + "/>";
        +"</object>";

        //alert("obj2String "+obj2String);

        var obj2String = "<object classid='clsid:" + DW_PROCLASSID + "'>"
                + "<param name='LPKPath' value='" + LPK_Path + "'" + "/>";
        +"</object>";

        var objects_string = obj2String + " " + objString;
        console.log(objects_string);

        DWTContainer = document.getElementById(DW_DWTContainerID);
        DWTContainer.innerHTML = objects_string;

        loadFile();
    }
</script>

<form id="gform">
  <div id="gform:scan_area">

   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the object is ready when you call its methods/properties. You can verify the object status by checking the value of a property. Below is a simple sample:

```
window.onload = function (){
var DW_Seed;   // The seed used to detect the control.
DW_Seed = setInterval(DW_ControlDetect, 500);
}
function DW_ControlDetect() {
// If the ErrorCode is 0, it means the control is fully loaded.
if (DWObject.ErrorCode == 0) {
   // loadFile()...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be an issue with the scope of the var gform. Where is it declared? I don't see that anywhere in your code.

If that var is created in a different script, make sure that script is loaded before. Also make sure the gform var is created in the global scope. To make sure it is in the global scope you can attach it to `window`, (`window.gform = value`)

Comment: gform is declared in html page it's not created with script.

Comment: but gform in your example is a javascript variable, so it must be assigned somewhere, right?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the file loading function as it seemed irrelevant, your code's syntax was incorrect, I corrected it and now it is working and I could select the objects from the document .. check it out:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var DW_DWTContainerID = "gform:scan_area";
    var DW_FULLCLASSID = "123456-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456"; // fixed
    var DW_PROCLASSID = "3d25aba1-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456";  // the one in lpk file

    var DW_VersionCode = "6,3,1,0";
    var DW_InWindowsX86;
    var objString = "";

    var DW_ObjectName="MOJWebTwain";
    var DW_Width = 400;
    var DW_Height = 400;
    var DW_CABX86Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAIN.cab";
    var DW_CABX64Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAINx64.cab";
    var LPK_Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTwain.lpk";
    ua = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

    objString += "<object id='" + DW_ObjectName + "' "+"width='" + DW_Width +" ' "+"height='" + DW_Height+"' ";

    if (DW_InWindowsX86) objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX86Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";
    else objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX64Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";

    objString += " classid='clsid:" + DW_FULLCLASSID + "' viewastext>";

    //alert("objString: "+objString);

    objString += " <param name='_cx' value='847'/>";
    objString += " <param name='_cy' value='847'/>";
    objString += " <param name='JpgQuality' value='30'/>";
    objString += " <param name='Manufacturer' value='DynamSoft Corporation'/>";
    objString += " <param name='ProductFamily' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN'/>";
    objString += " <param name='ProductName' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN'/>";
    objString += " <param name='VersionInfo' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN 6,3,1,0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='TransferMode' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='BorderStyle' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='FTPUserName' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='FTPPassword' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='FTPPort' value='21'/>";
    objString += " <param name='HTTPUserName' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='HTTPPassword' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='HTTPPort' value='9080' />";
    objString += " <param name='ProxyServer' value=''/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfDisableSourceAfterAcquire' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfShowUI' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfModalUI' value='-1'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfTiffMultiPage' value='-1'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfThrowException' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='MaxImagesInBuffer' value='99'/>";
    objString += " <param name='TIFFCompressionType' value='0'/>";
    objString += " <param name='IfFitWindow' value='-1' />";
    objString += " <param name='IfSSL' value='0' />";
    objString += " </object>";

    var obj2String = "<object classid='clsid:"+DW_PROCLASSID+"'>"+"<param name='LPKPath' value='"+LPK_Path+"'"+"/>"+"</object>";

    //alert("obj2String "+obj2String);

    /* var obj2String = "<object classid='clsid:"+DW_PROCLASSID+"'>"+"<param name='LPKPath' value='"+LPK_Path+"'"+"/>";
        +"</object>"; */

    var objects_string=obj2String +" "+objString;

    var DWTContainer = document.getElementById(DW_DWTContainerID);                          
    DWTContainer.innerHTML = objects_string;
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('FTPPassword')[0]);
    //loadFile();
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/odagop/1/edit)**

about the gform object, you didn't assign any object to that variable yet ! so yes it will be null or undeclared.

Note: I couldn't help but notice you are using alerts for testing, this will cause you a headache when you run in loops, better use console.log (safer & faster) as you see in this code, and check the browser's console for the results in inspection mode

Comment: sorry i didn't tried the code yet, but can you please specify the changes you made.

Comment: aha i noticed that you removed the part that was causing the issue which is not a solution, in the onload function i initialize the webtwain object responsible for creating a scan area, and the load function is important because it's used to load file from hard disk to scan area, so you simply can't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

@Mahmoud try the below code, I was not able to check your code with Jsfiddle (is there a way to provide credentials to access your server ? to test?

```
function loadFile() {
    alert("loading file");
    gform.MOJWebTwain.HTTPPort = 9080;
    gform.MOJWebTwain.IfSSL = false;
    var result = gform.MOJWebTwain.HTTPDownload('myServer', existingDocumentPath);
    alert("result: "+result);
    var errorString = gform.MOJWebTwain.ErrorString;
    var errorCode = gform.MOJWebTwain.ErrorCode;
    if (!result) {
        alert("errorString: " + errorString);
        alert("errorCode " + errorCode);
    }
    document.body.style.opacity="100";

}

window.onload = function () {
var DW_DWTContainerID = "gform:scan_area";
var DW_FULLCLASSID = "123456-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456"; // fixed
var DW_PROCLASSID = "3d25aba1-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456";  // the one in lpk file

var DW_VersionCode = "6,3,1,0";
var DW_InWindowsX86;
var objString = "";

var DW_ObjectName="MOJWebTwain"
var DW_Width = 400;
var DW_Height = 400;
var DW_CABX86Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAIN.cab";
var DW_CABX64Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAINx64.cab";
var LPK_Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTwain.lpk";
ua = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

objString += "<object id='" + DW_ObjectName + "' "+"width='" + DW_Width +" ' "+"height='" + DW_Height+"' ";

if (DW_InWindowsX86) objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX86Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";
else objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX64Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";

objString += " classid='clsid:" + DW_FULLCLASSID + "' viewastext>";

//alert("objString: "+objString);

objString += " <param name='_cx' value='847'/>";
objString += " <param name='_cy' value='847'/>";
objString += " <param name='JpgQuality' value='30'/>";
objString += " <param name='Manufacturer' value='DynamSoft Corporation'/>";
objString += " <param name='ProductFamily' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN'/>";
objString += " <param name='ProductName' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN'/>";
objString += " <param name='VersionInfo' value='Dynamic Web TWAIN 6,3,1,0'/>";
objString += " <param name='TransferMode' value='0'/>";
objString += " <param name='BorderStyle' value='0'/>";
objString += " <param name='FTPUserName' value=''/>";
objString += " <param name='FTPPassword' value=''/>";
objString += " <param name='FTPPort' value='21'/>";
objString += " <param name='HTTPUserName' value=''/>";
objString += " <param name='HTTPPassword' value=''/>";
objString += " <param name='HTTPPort' value='9080' />";
objString += " <param name='ProxyServer' value=''/>";
objString += " <param name='IfDisableSourceAfterAcquire' value='0'/>";
objString += " <param name='IfShowUI' value='0'/>";
objString += " <param name='IfModalUI' value='-1'/>";
objString += " <param name='IfTiffMultiPage' value='-1'/>";
objString += " <param name='IfThrowException' value='0'/>";
objString += " <param name='MaxImagesInBuffer' value='99'/>";
objString += " <param name='TIFFCompressionType' value='0'/>";
objString += " <param name='IfFitWindow' value='-1' />";
objString += " <param name='IfSSL' value='0' />";
objString += " </object>";

var obj2String = "<object "
    +"classid='clsid:"+DW_PROCLASSID+"'"+">"
    +"<param name='LPKPath' value='"+LPK_Path+"'"+"/>";
    +"</object>";

//alert("obj2String "+obj2String);

var obj2String = "<object classid='clsid:"+DW_PROCLASSID+"'>"
    +"<param name='LPKPath' value='"+LPK_Path+"'"+"/>";
    +"</object>";

var objects_string=obj2String +" "+objString;

DWTContainer = document.getElementById(DW_DWTContainerID);                          
DWTContainer.innerHTML = objects_string;

setInterval(function(){loadFile()},1000); // this will delay it by a second just in case some other instructions should be done ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Rachel, you can try the below:

```
function loadFile() {
    gform.MOJWebTwain.HTTPPort = 9080;
    gform.MOJWebTwain.IfSSL = false;
    var result = gform.MOJWebTwain.HTTPDownload('myServer', existingDocumentPath);
    alert("result: "+result);
    var errorString = gform.MOJWebTwain.ErrorString;
    var errorCode = gform.MOJWebTwain.ErrorCode;
    if (!result) {
        alert("errorString: " + errorString);
        alert("errorCode " + errorCode);
    }
    document.body.style.opacity="100";
}    

window.onload = function () {
    var DW_DWTContainerID = "gform:scan_area";
    var DW_FULLCLASSID = "123456-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456"; // fixed
    var DW_PROCLASSID = "3d25aba1-abcdef-12345-abcdef-123456";  // the one in lpk file

    var DW_VersionCode = "6,3,1,0";
    var DW_InWindowsX86;
    var objString = "";

    var DW_ObjectName="MOJWebTwain"
    var DW_Width = 400;
    var DW_Height = 400;
    var DW_CABX86Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAIN.cab";
    var DW_CABX64Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTWAINx64.cab";
    var LPK_Path = "DynamSoft/DynamicWebTwain.lpk";
    ua = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
    if (ua.indexOf("win64") != -1 && ua.indexOf("x64") != -1)
        DW_InWindowsX86 = false;
    else
        DW_InWindowsX86 = true;
    objString += "<object id='" + DW_ObjectName + "' "+"width='" + DW_Width +" ' "+"height='" + DW_Height+"' ";

    if (DW_InWindowsX86) objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX86Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";
    else objString += "codebase='" + DW_CABX64Path + "#version=" + DW_VersionCode + "' ";

    objString += " classid='clsid:" + DW_FULLCLASSID + "' viewastext>";
    objString += " </object>"; 

    var obj2String = "<object "
        +"classid='clsid:"+DW_PROCLASSID+"'"+">"
        +"<param name='LPKPath' value='"+LPK_Path+"'"+"/>";
        +"</object>";

    var objects_string=obj2String +" "+objString;

    DWTContainer = document.getElementById(DW_DWTContainerID);                          
    DWTContainer.innerHTML = objects_string;
    DW_Seed;   // The seed used to detect the control.
    DW_Seed = setInterval(DW_ControlDetect, 500);

}
function DW_ControlDetect() {
    if (gform.MOJWebTwain.ErrorCode == 0) {
        loadFile();
    }
}
```